# tried a lot but not able to make deletehandler function working. here is my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, api

This is my librarylist component in which i pass deletehandler function to delete the row from library management. I don't know which part of the code is causing the problem. Any helps/suggestions are welcome.
**LibraryBookList.js**

```
 const LibraryBookList = (props) => {
 const[database, setDatabase]=useState()
 const deleteHandler = (bookdataId) => {

 const newDatabase=[...database];

 const index= database.findIndex((bookdata)=>bookdata.id===bookdataId)

 newDatabase.splice(index,1)

setDatabase(newDatabase);
} ;

return (
<ul className={classes.list}>
  {props.database.map((bookdata) => 
     (<LibraryBook

      key={bookdata.key}
      id={bookdata.id}
      bookname={bookdata.bookName}
      author={bookdata.author}
      publisher={bookdata.publisher}
      pages={bookdata.pages}
      serialno={bookdata.serialNo}
      onSelect={deleteHandler}
    />
  ))}
</ul>
   )};
```

here i pass deletehandler via props
**LibraryBook.js**

```
 const LibraryBook = (props) => {

 return (
  <li>
  <table className={classes.table}>
    <tbody>
      <tr className={classes.table_row}>
        <td className={classes.row_data}>{props.serialno}</td>
        <td className={classes.row_data}>{props.pages}</td>
        <td className={classes.row_data}>{props.bookname}</td>
        <td className={classes.row_data}>{props.author}</td>
        <td className={classes.row_data}>{props.publisher}</td>
        <td>
          <button className={classes.delete_btn} onClick={(props.onSelect(props.id))}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</li>
export default LibraryBookList;
```

**BookData.js **

```
 const BookData = (props) => {
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
 const [loadedLibrarydata, setLoadedLibrarydata] = useState();
 useEffect(() => {
 setIsLoading(true);
 fetch(
  "https://librarymanagement-70ab2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/database.json"
  )
  .then((response) => {
    // console.log('response',response.json())
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const database = [];
    console.log("data", data);
    for (const key in data) {
      const bookdata = {
        id: key,
        ...data[key],
      };
      database.push(bookdata);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
    setLoadedLibrarydata(database);
  });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
  return (
  <section>
    <p>Loading.....</p>
  </section>
);
}

return (
<section>
  <h1>Book Data Base</h1>
  <table className={classes.table}>
    <thead>
      <tr className={classes.table_row}>
        <th className={classes.row_heading}>Serial No</th>
        <th className={classes.row_heading}>Pages</th>
        <th className={classes.row_heading}>Book Name</th>
        <th className={classes.row_heading}>Author</th>
        <th className={classes.row_heading}>Publisher</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  {loadedLibrarydata && loadedLibrarydata.length && (
    <LibraryBooklist database={loadedLibrarydata} />
   )}
 </section>
 );
 };
 export default BookData;
```

**NewDataBase.js**

```
 const NewDataBase = () => {
 const history=useHistory();

  const addDataHandler = (bookData) => {
   console.log('bookData',bookData);
   fetch(
    "https://librarymanagement-70ab2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/database.json",
    {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(bookData),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
   }
  ).then(()=>{
  history.replace('/')

   })
   };
  return (
 <section>
  <DataBaseForm onAddNewData={addDataHandler} />
 </section>
  );
   };
  export default NewDataBase;
```

Comment: `onClick={() => props.onSelect(props.id)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has a few issues: 1) `props.onSelect(props.id)` inside `onClick`. Instead you should give a referance to that function. 2) You didn't have anything in `database` state before you click delete button. That is why `...` spread operator didn't work 3) You are displaying `props.database` instead of `database` state. That is way the changes didn't show up even after you deleted a bookdata. I also fixed some small issues. Now it is working perfectly:

```
// !! you can put all the code into one file and run for testing.
// !! I removed stylings as I didn't have the source
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const LibraryBooklist = (props) => {
  const[database, setDatabase]=useState(props.database)
  const deleteHandler = (bookdataId) => {
    const newDatabase=database.filter((bookdata)=>bookdata.id!==bookdataId);
    setDatabase(newDatabase);
  }

  return (
  <ul>
  {database.map((bookdata) => 
      <LibraryBook
        key={bookdata.id}
        id={bookdata.id}
        bookname={bookdata.bookName}
        author={bookdata.author}
        publisher={bookdata.publisher}
        pages={bookdata.pages}
        serialno={bookdata.serialNo}
        onSelect={deleteHandler}
      />
  )}
  </ul>
)};


const LibraryBook = (props) => {
 const {id, onSelect} = props
 return (
  <li>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{props.serialno}</td>
        <td>{props.pages}</td>
        <td>{props.bookname}</td>
        <td>{props.author}</td>
        <td>{props.publisher}</td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</li>
)}

const BookData = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadedLibrarydata, setLoadedLibrarydata] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(
    "https://librarymanagement-70ab2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/database.json"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      // console.log('response',response.json())
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const database = [];
      
      for (const key in data) {
        const bookdata = {
          id: key,
          ...data[key],
        };
        database.push(bookdata);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
      setLoadedLibrarydata(database);
    });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
    <section>
      <p>Loading.....</p>
    </section>
    );
  }

  return (
  <section>
    <h1>Book Data Base</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Serial No</th>
          <th>Pages</th>
          <th>Book Name</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Publisher</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    {loadedLibrarydata && loadedLibrarydata.length && (
      <LibraryBooklist database={loadedLibrarydata} />
    )}
  </section>
  );
};

export default BookData;
```

Comment: Let me know if this solved your problem

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that more people can benefit later

Comment: please suggest another solution it is still showing above error on clicking delete button

Comment: my problem is still not resolved

Comment: @ ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOB
then where i will put newdatabase??

Comment: now it is not showing any error but still not able to delete the row